# How can I have APF block script kiddies that mod_security detects?

Tags: security, firewall, mod-security

In one of the vhosts' error_log I found thousands of lines like these, all from the same IP:

`[Mon Apr 19 08:15:59 2010] [error] [client 61.147.67.206] mod_security: Access denied with code 403. Pattern match "(chr|fwrite|fopen|system|e?chr|passthru|popen|proc_open|shell_exec|exec|proc_nice|proc_terminate|proc_get_status|proc_close|pfsockopen|leak|apache_child_terminate|posix_kill|posix_mkfifo|posix_setpgid|posix_setsid|posix_setuid|phpinfo)\\\\(.*\\\\)\\\\;" at THE_REQUEST [id "330001"] [rev "1"] [msg "Generic PHP exploit pattern denied"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "x.x.x.x"] [uri "//webmail/config.inc.php?p=phpinfo();"]`

Given how obvious the situation is, how come mod_security isnt automatically adding at least that IP to deny rules? There is no way someone hasnt thought of this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's from the same IP, perhaps you should just block it on the firewall level?

But for APF [this post](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mod_security-rules-49176.html#post235016) should help.

Comment: I already blocked the entire class C via APF (it's in china. we have absolutely no interest in chinese visitors.), but my question is exactly how do I make this happen automatically?

Comment: You can write a script analyze our log file for `mod_security: Access denied with code 403`, extract the IP address, count a number of times it appears in the log, and if exceeds some kind of threshold, run a command to block that IP.

Comment: that would be beyond my skill level... unless you want to assist with such script. what do you recommend? a perl script, cron'ed to run every 5 minutes, that reads the log file and adds to deny.rules when condition X is true?

off topic: i've been a windows admin for a over a decade. i'm using LAMP because the best web applications (such as wordpress) run better on it, but damn so many simple basic things become so complicated in linux...

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty shell one-liner that can extract the IP addresses, and count them. `grep "mod_security: Access denied with code 403" access.log | awk -F\  '{print $8}' | sed -e s/\]// | uniq -c | sort`.

Run this command but replace `access.log` with the pass to your log file. See if it works for you. 

You can have a shell script run every time apache log rotates. No need to run it from cron, really.

Comment: thanks, i will give it a try. how do i set the script to run when the log rotates?